# Invalid attributes given, name is missing Cognito New Password Required

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to reset the password of the user in the Cognito pool. I am using the following code to acheive that.

```
import {
  ChallengeNameType,
  CognitoIdentityProviderClient,
  RespondToAuthChallengeCommand,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider";
import { ResetPassword } from "interfaces/types";

export class CognitoResetPasswordServiceWrapper {
  private cognitoClient: CognitoIdentityProviderClient;

  constructor() {
    this.cognitoClient = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({
      region: process.env.REGION,
    });
  }

  async resetPassword(event: ResetPassword) {
    try {
      const { email, newPassword, session } = event;

      const command = new RespondToAuthChallengeCommand({
        ClientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        ChallengeName: ChallengeNameType.NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED,
        ChallengeResponses: { USERNAME: email, NEW_PASSWORD: newPassword },
        Session: session,
      });

      const response = await this.cognitoClient.send(command);
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to execute the command, I am getting this error.

> {
> "status": "Failed",
> "message": "Invalid attributes given, name is missing",
> "body": {
> "name": "InvalidParameterException",
> "$fault": "client",
> "$metadata": {
> "httpStatusCode": 400,
> "requestId": "a9aee27d-19ce-4f49-a7b1-1de15fbb7046",
> "attempts": 1,
> "totalRetryDelay": 0
> },
> "__type": "InvalidParameterException"
> } }

What can be the issue here.

Comment: I think you also need to pass name `'userAttributes.name': '<>'` inside `ChallengeResponses`.